# Discontinuity of the Laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I'm searching for a proof of the following fact:

> For every $d$ there is a sequence $\{\phi_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ that converges to $0$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, such that $\Delta \phi_n$ does not converge to $0$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

As I couldn't find a proof anywhere, I'd appreciate it if anyone could sketch an example of such sequence.

Comment: I think you should clarify what $n$'s role is here. You used $n$ to define your vector space and you also used it to denote a sequence. It's a little confusing. Also when referring to $C_c^{\infty}$, do you mean the compactly-supported smooth functions?

Comment: I made a small edit, so it should be clear now. As for $C_c^{\infty}$, yes, I mean compactly-supported smooth functions.

Comment: For $d=1$, try something like a Gaussian $\frac{1}{\sigma}e^{-(x/\sigma)^2}$ with $\sigma\to 0$. The intuition is that this will remain bounded above and go to zero pointwise except at $x=0$, thus go to zero in $L^2$, while its Laplacian will stay away from zero as the curvature near the tip of the distribution grows without bound.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe an easy example in $ [0,1] $ first, something like $ \frac{1}{n} \sin(n \pi x) $. Now you can extend to $ \mathbb{R} $ smoothly with some bump function.

Note: Neal's example of gaussian is nicer, but I think he didn't mean $ \frac{1}{\sigma} $ as a prefactor? It is also not compactly supported.